# Disabling Browser Refresh icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to disable browser reload/refresh button on mouse click and also enter event on address bar so that user can not load or refresh page. I restrict F5, ctrl + F5 key so now page didn't refresh or reload, but still user can page reload on mouse click on browser reload icon.
So, I want to disable or stop working browser reload button. I don't want to confirmation message or warning message on reload button click.

Comment: No browser should/would allow that... Maybe you can try some extension but from pure JS/HTML, you can't.

Comment: This is not possible for a lot of obvious reasons. If you feel the need to do this then you need to take a larger look at how you've structured your application and find another way, as restricting user behaviour is never an acceptable solution.